# PHP ошибка в работе с класссами

Tags: php, классы

Имеется файл html.php в котором есть абстрактный класс HTMLPage

```
<?php 
abstract class HTMLPage 
{
    public function __construct($Title) 
    {
        $this ->Title = $Title;
        echo "<title>".$Title."</title>";
    }
    public function BeginHTML() 
    {
        echo "<html>
              <head>
              <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
              <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">
              </head>
              <body>";
    }
    public function EndHTML()
    {
        echo "</body>
              </html>";
    }
    public function Logo()
    {
        echo "<div class=\"Logo\"><img src\"Images\Logo.jpg\"</div>";
    }
    public function Menu()
    {
        echo "<ul class=\"menu\">
              <li><a href=#>Menu 1</a>
              <ul class=\"submenu\">
              <li><a href=#>Первая достопримечательность</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>";
    }
    public abstract function MainText();
    public function Write()
    {
        __construct($Title);
        BeginHTML();
        Logo();
        Menu();
        MainText();
        EndHTML();
    }
}

?>
```

Пытаюсь создать дочерний класс Editor и вызвать функцию Write() в файле index.php

```
<?php
include('html.php');

class Editor extends HTMLPage 
{
    public function MainText()
    {
        echo "Текст";
    }
}
$Title = "Главная страница";
$edit = new Editor();
$edit->Write();

?>
```

Выдает лог ошибки:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for HTMLPage::__construct(), called in
>   D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\LABS\Sem4\lab2\index.php on
>   line 13 and defined in
>   D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\LABS\Sem4\lab2\html.php on
>   line 4
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function __construct() in
>   D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\localhost\LABS\Sem4\lab2\html.php on
>   line 39

Comment: Откуда брать $Title? Просто переведи текст сообщения

Comment: @MykolaVeriga мне надо создать и инициализировать объект (в данном случае заголовок страницы), это видимо надо по-другому задать чтобы не выдавало undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша основная ошибка в том, что вы путаете **методы** класса с **функциями**. Например, в методе `Write()` вы прописали вызовы функций *(именно функций, а не методов класса)* `BeginHTML()`, `Logo()`, и т.д., а надо было вызывать методы: `$this->BeginHTML()`, `$this->Logo()`, и т.д..

Следующая ошибка - вы не предоставили данных для конструктора класса. Нужно вместо  `$edit = new Editor();` записать так: `$edit = new Editor('Главная страница');`, и в теле абстрактного класса для наглядности объявить свойство `$Title` с модификатором `public`.

Строку `__construct()` надо удалить из метода `Write()`, а в теле конструктора абстрактного класса надо удалить строку `echo "<title>".$Title."</title>";`, и записать её в метод `BeginHTML()`.

И последнее, на что я хотел бы обратить ваше внимание, это обилие обратных слешей `"\"`. Чтобы не уродовать html-код, достаточно использовать одиночные кавычки для обозначения начала и конца строки в php. Ваше решение в исправленном виде:

```
abstract class HTMLPage 
{
    public $Title;

    public function __construct($Title) 
    {
        $this->Title = $Title;
    }

    public function BeginHTML() 
    {
        echo
        '<!DOCTYPE html>'.
        "\n".'<html>'.
        "\n".'<head>'.
            "\n\t".'<meta charset="UTF-8">'.
            "\n\t".'<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">'.
            "\n\t".'<title>'. $this->Title .'</title>'.
        "\n".'</head>'.
        "\n".'<body>'."\n\n";
    }

    public function EndHTML()
    {
        echo
        "\n\n".'</body>'.
        "\n".'</html>';
    }

    public function Logo()
    {
        echo '<div class="Logo"><img src="Images/Logo.jpg"></div>';
    }

    public function Menu()
    {
        echo
        '<ul class="menu">'.
            '<li>'.
                '<a href="#">Menu 1</a>'.
                '<ul class="submenu">'.
                    '<li><a href="#">Первая достопримечательность</a></li>'.
                '</ul>'.
            '</li>'.
        '</ul>';
    }

    public abstract function MainText();

    public function Write()
    {
        $this->BeginHTML();
        $this->Logo();
        $this->Menu();
        $this->MainText();
        $this->EndHTML();
    }
}


class Editor extends HTMLPage 
{
    public function MainText()
    {
        echo 'Текст';
    }
}

$Title = 'Главная страница';

$edit = new Editor($Title);
$edit->Write();
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом методе переменная $Title не инициализирована. Нельзя использовать переменную  не объявив ее.

Еще метод `__construct` не нужно вызывать, он будет вызван интерпритатором PHP в момент создания нового объекта класса. То есть во время `new HTMLPage($Title)`;

```
public function Write()
{
    __construct($Title);
    BeginHTML();
    Logo();
    Menu();
    MainText();
    EndHTML();
}
```

Один из верных вариантов:

```
public function Write($Title)
{
    new HTMLPage($Title);
    BeginHTML();
    Logo();
    Menu();
    MainText();
    EndHTML();
}
```